# AngularJS : How to execute function in pre-defined order?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have following receiver in my AngularJS Controller:

```
   // Receive broadcast
        $rootScope.$on('setPlayListEvent', function(event, playListData) {
          if($scope.someSoundsArePlaying === true) {
             $scope.stopAllSelectedSounds();
          }
            $scope.setPlaylistToView(playListData);
        });
```

But it seems, that method called setPlaylistToView is always called and executed before the code:

```
 if($scope.someSoundsArePlaying === true) {
                 $scope.stopAllSelectedSounds();
              }
```

And so it can affect the result of the method.

I would like to ask, how can i set " execution order" of functions? Something like resolve..then..

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You haven't shown us what `stopAllSelectedSounds` does.

Comment: does `$scope.someSoundsArePlaying` is returning a promise or something else

Comment: redrom, did my answer answered your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded so you don't want to hold the thread, therefor a possible way to handle your issue is using a promise.

I would have write the code in the following way:

```
function stopAllSelectedSounds() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  //Perform logic

  //if logic performed successfuly
  deferred.resolve();

  //if logic failed
  deferred.reject('reason is blah');

  return deferred.promise;
}

$scope.stopAllSelectedSounds().then(function() {
  alert('Success');
  $scope.setPlaylistToView(playListData);
}, function(reason) {
  alert('Failed ' + reason);
});
```

This way only when stopAllSelectedSounds is successfully executed you will execute setPlaylistToView without halting the entire app.

see - [Angular's Q documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

> A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their
>   return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing.